# Compare columns in SQL Select without additional select statement

Tags: sql, select, plsql

I'm currently writing a relatively complex SQL statement which selects data from multiple tables and has quite a few sub-statements and joins.
In my "final" data set, I want to return raw data as well as comparisons between the raw data. While I can do this when the raw data is found using a Join, is it possible to do this while the raw data is found in a sub-query?

For example:
If I have a query which is

```
SELECT
A
,(SELECT B FROM BETA WHERE Row = ALPHA.Betalink) B
FROM APLHA
WHERE A > 1
```

Can I add a column which compares A and B without adding another Select?

The only way I know to solve this would be to do the above select, then select on that:

```
SELECT
A
,B
,greater(A,B)
FROM
(SELECT A
 ,(SELECT B FROM BETA WHERE Row = ALPHA.Betalink) B
 FROM APLHA
 WHERE A > 1
)
```

TIA

Comment: Correlated subqueries tend to behave badly in many cases.  Unless you have a good reason, avoid them.  For your general question, it's probably better to explain the real requirement, with actual relationships (create table statements) and constraints, with sample data (insert statements), along with the expected result, given that data.

Comment: In the trivial / fake example shown, use a simple / inner join, instead of correlated behavior.  There's no need for any subquery in that example.  Just join alpha with beta and compare B directly with A, based on that join. Done.  The `A > 1` logic can be in your `WHERE` clause or directly in the `ON` clause.

Comment: no, the way to go is to make a outer sql, where you gather all relevant data in the inner select and the make as may outer select as you need to get your data. correlated subqueries are ok, the parser handles them like inner  joins, so there is no need for inner joins at all

Comment: While I understand the desire to avoid correlated joins, can we assume that I need to use them and move from there? I agree that my example doesn't require them.

Comment: Sure. You could create a derived column using that subquery, if that's what you wish, or directly from the JOIN I showed.  No additional subquery is required.  `greatest(A, (SELECT B FROM ...)) AS compared ...`.

Comment: Check out the `with` clause. In many cases its faster than normal subquery (Oracle DB optimizes the query by treating the query name as an inline view or as a temporary table), and you can use joins on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a `with` clause.
What is the most important- the query is ran once, while subquery is runned for every returned row.
You can read about it here:
[subquery_factoring_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF30048)

In your example it could look like this:

```
WITH SUBQ_DATA as (SELECT B,Row FROM BETA) 
SELECT alpha.A
      ,sub.B
      ,greater(alpha.A,sub.B)
FROM ALPHA alpha
JOIN SUBQ_DATA sub on sub.Row = alpha.Betalink
WHERE A > 1
```